# Unable to insert values into existing work book [apache poi]

Tags: java, apache-poi

I would like to insert values into existing work book. Here the class that encapsulates this logic:

```
public class FormulaExtractor {
private String pathToExcelFile;
private XSSFWorkbook workbook;
private Map<Double, Formula> idFormular = new HashMap<>();

public FormulaExtractor(String pathToExcelFile) {
    this.pathToExcelFile = pathToExcelFile;
    try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToExcelFile))) {
        this.workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Cannot locate a xls file. Exception: " + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO exception " + e.toString());
    }
}

public void insertHumanReadableFormulas() throws IOException {
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row currentRow = rowIterator.next();
        Cell cell = currentRow.createCell(CellReference.convertColStringToIndex("K"));
        cell.setCellValue("Some dummy variable to test. ");
    }

FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(new File(this.pathToExcelFile));
    workbook.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
}
```

}

How do I use it:

```
public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final String pathToExcel = "some/path/some_excel.xlsx";
    FormulaExtractor formulaExtractor = new FormulaExtractor(pathToExcel);

    formulaExtractor.insertHumanReadableFormulas();
    }
}
```

I don't get any exception or error. When I open my excel file, I simply cannot find values in a column "K". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you say you can't do it - why not?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: I don't get any exception or error. When I open my excel file, I simply cannot find values in a column "K".

Comment: What is your question? what exactly is the error that you are getting?

Comment: I tried your code with `poi-ooxml-3.10.1.jar` it works like you expect. Are you checking the right file? Have you tried it with a newly created `*.xlsx` file which contains no other data.